# Selenium Python- IndexError: list index out of range on iterating through a table

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am getting  IndexError: list index out of range on iterating through html table but I am not sure what is causing it. Below is the function I wrote to iterate through the table.In each iteration it performs a click (one frame of webpage) and downloads files(which is in another frame)  . The table has 20 rows. It works fine when the web page loads properly. But once the webpage hangs  (ie frame where download happens), my code enters the timeout exception and gets to the top of the code . After that, i get the out of index error on line "employeeList[j].click()" .On debugging, I found out that previous line employeeList returns an empty list . Can someone please explain what is causing  this issue.

```
def candidate():

    for j in range(0,20):

        driver.implicitly_wait(50)   
        employeeList=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[7]/div/div[1]/a")
        employeeList[j].click()
        driver.switch_to_default_content()
        driver.implicitly_wait(50)
        driver.switch_to.frame("detail")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,2)

        try:                
            resume = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='menubar']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a/span")))
            driver.implicitly_wait(50)
            resume.click()
            download = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[@title="Download Resume"]')))

            driver.implicitly_wait(50)
            download.click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(50)
            driver.switch_to.frame("RTFVIEWER_MS")
            msword =  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='pagecontainer'>>]/div/a[2]/ul/li[2]")))
            driver.implicitly_wait(50)            
            msword.click()
            print(j)
        except TimeoutException as ex1:
            print("Exception has been thrown"+str(ex1))
            print(j)
            continue

        driver.switch_to_default_content()
        driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

Comment: "On debugging, I found out that previous line employeeList returns an empty list . Can someone please explain what is causing this issue."  Since `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[7]/div/div[1]/a")` returns an empty list I would presume the problem is with your xpath.

Comment: Hi Steven, the xpath works fine when it runs without entering the except block. This happens only when the code returns to the top after moving through the except part

Comment: Prior to the try block you `driver.switch_to.frame("detail")`.  In the try block you `driver.switch_to.frame("RTFVIEWER_MS")`.  When you have a timeout exception you never get the switch to frame `RTFVIEWER_MS`. You don't switch the frame when handling the exception.  My guess would be that your xpath works on frame `RTFVIEWER_MS` and not on frame `detail`.

Comment: Are the lines `driver.switch_to_default_content()` and `driver.switch_to.frame(0)` inside your for-loop our outside of it? When you originally posted your code it was inside and now it's outside, but it seems that you have trouble formatting code in your question so I don't quite trust the current indentation.  If they are supposed to be inside the for-loop than when you `continue` in your except-clause they are skipped and that would be the source of your bug.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue . The continue statement returned to the top of the function without switching frames . Thanks Steven for pointing that out.

Comment: driver.switch_to_default_content() and driver.switch_to.frame(0) is inside my for-loop . Sorry for the confusion , some trouble with formatting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[7]/div/div[1]/a")` fails after a `TimeoutException` because some lines get skipped due to how you handle the exception.

The last line of your for-loop sets the driver back to the original frame `driver.switch_to.frame(0)` where the xpath worked.  When you have an exception you are doing a `continue` in the except-clause and skipping the final lines of the for-loop.  Either don't `continue` or do the needed cleanup in your except-clause.